# Php y Mysqli claves encriptadas

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Buenas, lo que pasa es que estoy super perdido con esto de las claves encriptadas en php..... tengo un codigo que ya me guarda en la base de datos las claves (ya encriptadas) mi problema ahora es como verificarlas, tengo el siguiente codigo, supongo que estara mal gran parte, e investigado y no le encuentro solucion, e cargado la password encriptada en una variable, pero password_verifi no me funciona,el numero 5 nada mas es una prueba, ya que es la contraseña de una cuenta que tengo guardada, aun asi me tira el error de no es valida, ayuda....

```
<?php

$mysqli= new mysqli("localhost", "root","", "sistema");



$nombre =isset($_POST['usuario']) ? $_POST['usuario'] : null ;
$contra =isset($_POST['contra']) ? $_POST['contra'] : null ;


 $query="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario='$nombre'";

 $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);

 $row=$resultado->fetch_assoc();

 $hash= $row['password']; 

 echo $hash;


if (password_verify('5', $hash)) {
echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';

} else {
echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
}
?>
```

Comment: El campo passwors se la base fue previamente hasheado con password_hash?

Comment: si, en otro formulario, en la base las contraseñas ya estan encriptadas, las quiero sacar de ahi y verificarlas

Comment: Pero jas hasheaste con password_ hash? O usaste un algoritmo en particular: md5, sha1, mcrypt, bcript...

Comment: $passHash = password_hash($contra, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); este

Comment: El problema no esta en `password_*` ([`ver ejemplo`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5e45044494d88f9679c4dee79654c81b85c0ff97)) ... que resultado te da por ejemplo `echo $hash`?

Comment: si ya hiciste el HASH la primera ves que lo guardaste (al crear el usuario), solo debes compararlo con con el que envien la segunda vez.   password->hash   ===  passwordEnLaBBDD y  listo.. no tienes que re-hashear el password que obtienes de la BBDD

Comment: Ya probaste con `if (password_verify($contra, $hash))` ? Podrías imprimir lo que recibes como $contra.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero mires la documentación  *http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php* en la misma notaras que para dicha comparación el Hash que tienes guardado debió ser obtenido con `password_hash()`; prueba si el valor de `$row['password']` es el mismo que obtiene con `password_hash($contra)`.